# Single line Initialization of Array of Structures

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to declare and initialize array of structure in one line. But it looks it is not supported like we do in arrays. In below code, `myStructArray[3]` gives error whereas `myStructArray2[3]` works OK. Why initialization in one line is not allowed (I know it is not a good practice to do, but still want to know the reason if any.)

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
       int structMemInt;
       char structMemChar;
}MYSTRUCT;

int main (void)
{
     struct myStruct myStructArray[3] = {2,'a',5,'b',7,'c'};

     struct myStruct myStructArray2[3] = {
         {2,'a'},
         {5,'b'},
         {7,'c'},
     };
}
```

Updated:

The point here is about one line initialization without separate braces for each array member vs with braces. That means why it does not work with `{2,'a',5,'b',7,'c'}` and why it is a must to include braces `{{2,'a'},{5,'b'},{7,'c'}}`?

I was comparing the behavior with multi dimensional array wherein we need not separate each row data with braces.
This doubt started because Theory and Problems of Programming with C by Byron Gottfried (Schaum outline series) explains in example 9.16 (whatever edition I have) in multi dimensional array section as below. So that means this book is wrong in wrong as far as two dimensional array initialization is concerned.

```
int values[3][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
```

[image]

Also one more book (I do not have the book details and I got from the web) says similar way (Attached second picture)

[image]

Comment: It has nothing to do with number of lines.. if u were to provide the oneliner as {{2,"a"}...} (note the extra level of {}, it should work the same.

Comment: @KarthikT: Sorry, my question was not clear. Updated the question.

Comment: So you've found a way that works and one that doesn't and you've realized that it's not the line breaks but the missing braces that cause the difference.  So, what is the question?

Comment: By the way, `int a[2][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};` is invalid syntax, too, although your compiler might “accept” it with a warning. The proper syntax is `int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};` and that really makes more sense, if you think about it.

Comment: There should be a close reason around "because that's the syntax of the language you use" ...

Comment: @JonWheelock it is a good thing that you need to add the extra {}. Just because you can with multidimensional arrays, doesn't mean you should, if only for the sanity of the future maintainers of the code. (read probably u in few days/months)

Comment: Karthik and 5gon12eder: Updated the question and the root cause for my confusion because of the book. Now it is clear that multidimensional array itself does not allow initialization without braces. I had understood differently because of these two books I was referring. Thanks for your inputs which made me to search for these books again and verify my original understanding. Hope you will remove my down votes!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you declare a structure type array. Each location of this array contain two type data one is integer and another is char. You can access each location by this way

```
myStructArray2[0].structMemInt=2;
myStructArray2[0].structMemChar='a';
myStructArray2[1].structMemInt=5;
myStructArray2[1].structMemChar='b';
myStructArray2[2].structMemInt=7;
myStructArray2[2].structMemChar='c';
```

Or

```
struct myStruct myStructArray2[3] = {
         {2,'a'}, //  location 0
         {5,'b'}, //  location 1
         {7,'c'}, //  location 2
     };
```

But

```
struct myStruct myStructArray[3] = {2,'a',5,'b',7,'c'};
```

this is not correct . hear you try to insert 6 items which is not exist in your structure declaration.

I think now you got your point.